# É possível o método main já vir escrito ao criar uma nova classe?

Tags: java, eclipse

Para agilizar o processo de criação da classe java gostaria que o método main sempre fosse escrito ao criar uma nova classe, como se fosse um atalho já integrado ao criar a classe, isso é possível ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, é possível. No momento da criação da classe, nas opções de criação, você pode selecionar que o método main seja escrito ao cria-la:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]